# Nx angular library and storybook not working

Tags: storybook, angular-library, nomachine-nx

I've just done the steps to install storybook on an angular project using nx, but when i run the storybook I get this message:

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selector')
**

Althought the storybook web runs well, there is no way to see my custom component in it, here is the screenshot:
[image]

and here it is the simple code for the Story on storybook for the button component:

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
import { PeButtonComponent } from './pe-button.component';

export default {
    title: 'PeButtonComponent',
    component: PeButtonComponent,
} as Meta<PeButtonComponent>;

export const Primary = {
    render: (args: PeButtonComponent) => ({
        props: args,
    }),
    args: {
        loading: false,
        style: 'primary',
        styleClass: '',
        disabled: false,
        icon: '',
        label: '',
    },
};
```

Any help would be more than welcome.

Thanks!

I tried to do in differents way the .stories.ts file for the component but there is no way to make it appear, if I use a common button this button is showed correctly.